# Busboy field values are empty during file upload with POST

Tags: node.js, file-upload, linux-mint, busboy

I'm using a request.post() from [Mikeal's Request Module](https://github.com/mikeal/request) on the client and processing it with [Busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy) on the server to upload a file.

On the server the:

```
busboy.on('field', function(fieldName, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated)
```

event fires the correct number of times with the expected fieldNames but the val is always empty. This is happening when I run the integration tests through mocha and when I use a browser against a locally running web server.

The catch is that this problem is not seen on the prod server or on other developers workstations. The other developers on the project (and the prod server) are running either MacOS or Ubuntu. I am running LinuxMint 17 on my workstation where I'm experiencing this problem.

The problem appears not to be an issue with the way that I'm using Request or Busboy (unless it's an edge case) but rather a configuration issue on my workstation causing this to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what solved the problem:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```